# Bash script to pass commands remotely via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, grep, find, io-redirection

i'm just starting out with bash & am trying to write a script to search specific files in a server remotely based on: (a)device name and (b) string. my goal is to get all output containing 'string' for the device specified. when i tried the script below just hangs. however, when i run the command directly on the server("grep -i "router1" /var/log/router.log | grep -i "UPDOWN"), it works. any ideas?any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
read -p "Enter username: " user
read -p "Enter device name: " dev
read -p "Enter string: " str
while read /home/user1/syslogs
do 
 ssh "$user"@server1234 'grep -i "$dev" /var/log/"$syslogs" 2> /dev/null | grep -i "$str"'
done
```

Comment: $syslogs -- syslogs is an uninitialized variable to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mis-using the `read` command. You don't specify the file to read from as an argument; `read` always reads from standard input. It's not clear what you want to do with the value you read from the file as a result, but you want something like this:

```
read -p "Enter username: " user
read -p "Enter device name: " dev
read -p "Enter string: " str

while read fileName; do
    # Also: I'm borrowing sputnick's solution to the nested quote problem.
    ssh $user@server1234 <<EOF
        grep -i "$dev" /var/log/$fileName 2>/dev/null | grep -i "$str"
EOF
done < /home/user1/syslogs
```

Comment: thanks for all the input so far. /home/user1/syslogs contains the specific file names to search in the server's /var/log directory. i'm trying to feed each file in the list to grep the contents for the whatever input we get as device name. will try to experiment further and update.

Comment: thanks chepner! i followed the modifications above & it now appears to be working with a few caveats:

Comment: 1. i do get the correct output but there's an error saying "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" 

2. i keep on getting prompted to enter the password.

Comment: To remove the pseudo-terminal error, call `ssh` with the `-t` option. To avoid having to enter a password, you'll have to set up private key authentication. There should be several questions here that can guide you through that process.

Answer (score 1):

The message `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal` is due to the fact that the `stdin` of the remote host's shell is being redirected from a here document and that there is no command specified for the remote host to execute, i. e. the remote host first assumes there will be a need to allocate a pseudo-terminal for an interactive login session due to the lacking command (see the synopsis of the `ssh` man page: `ssh ... [user@]hostname [command]`), but then realizes that the `stdin` of its shell is not a terminal since it is redirected from a here document. The result is that the remote host refuses to allocate a pseudo-terminal.

The solution in the given case would be to just specify a shell as a command for the remote host to execute the commands given in the here document.

As an alternative to specifying a shell as a command the remote host could be told in advance that there is no need for the allocation of a pseudo-terminal using the `-T` switch.

The `-t` switch, on the other hand, would be necessary only if a specified command expects an interactive login shell session on the remote host (such as `top` or `vim`).

```
- ssh $user@server1234 <<EOF ...
+ ssh $user@server1234 /bin/sh <<EOF ...
+ ssh -T $user@server1234 <<EOF ...
```